# using Retrofit enqueue calls getting problem

Tags: android, api, kotlin, retrofit, enqueue

getting this error for enqueue for kotlin android and it is showing Unresolved reference: enqueue

my code

```
class NewsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var mRecyclerView: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var mProgressBar: ProgressBar
    private lateinit var mAdapter: NewsAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news)

        mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)

        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_circular)

        getItemList()
    }

    private fun getItemList() {

        mProgressBar.visibility = View.VISIBLE

       val apical = ApiClient.create().getData()

        apical.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<List<DataModelItem>> {

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<List<DataModelItem>>, t: Throwable) {
                mProgressBar.visibility = View.GONE
            }

            override fun onResponse(
                call: Call<List<DataModelItem>>,
                response: Response<List<DataModelItem>>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful){
                    val itemListNews = response.body()!!

                    mAdapter = NewsAdapter(itemListNews)

                    val layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@NewsActivity)

                    mRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
                    mRecyclerView.adapter = mAdapter
                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

this is News activity

```
class NewsAdapter(private val itemList : List<DataModelItem>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.CustomViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): NewsAdapter.CustomViewHolder {
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.item_view, parent, false)
        return CustomViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: NewsAdapter.CustomViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val itemData = itemList.get(position)

        Picasso.get().load(itemData.images).into(holder.img1)
        holder.Titlenews.setText(itemData.title)
        holder.txt_description.setText(itemData.summary)
        holder.publish_time.setText(itemData.publish_date)

    }

    inner class CustomViewHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view){

        var img1:ImageView
        var Titlenews: TextView
        var txt_description: TextView
        var publish_time: TextView

        init {
            img1 = view.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
            Titlenews = view.findViewById(R.id.Titlenews)
            txt_description = view.findViewById(R.id.txt_description)
            publish_time = view.findViewById(R.id.publish_time)
        }

    }
}
```

this is the news adapter

```
object ApiClient {


    var BASE_URL = ""

    fun create() :Api{
         val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
             .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
             .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
             .build()

        return retrofit.create(Api::class.java)
    }
}
```

this is Api client

Help required

I want not getting a solution as always it is giving me an error for enqueue .

Comment: Can you show getData() method?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
    apical.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<List<DataModelItem>> {
```

to

```
 apical.enqueue(object : retrofit.Callback<List<DataModelItem>> {
```